# Connecting to ubuntu home server without internet connection

Tags: apache, ubuntu, bandwidth

I am running an Ubuntu server with my laptop through an Orcale VirtualBox and I try to maximize the bandwidth of my home server, as it really slows down my internet connection. My router supports up to 300Mbit upload/download speed and my laptop wifi's card up to 150bit.

I configured my server with the following(static IP, configured by vim /etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

192.168.1.1 is my default gateway, and I just configured a static IP which ends with 240.

When my laptop's WIFI is on, I can easily access the server's files(.html files etc) through chrome from any computer on my house, as I just need to enter the server's IP into the browser, plus I can access the server through SSH. But when It's off, I can't even access the server's HTML files through the laptop itself, though I can see that the server is still running on VirtualBox. When I turn the WIFI once again, I can run services which require Apache2 but they really slow my internet connection, as a result I can barely surf the web. I am trying to configure the server to use only the bandwidth of my router, since my actual internet connection is 30 Mbit download and 1.90 Mbit upload(according to speedtest), and It probably interferes with it. Is it possible to access the server without WIFI connection, so it will purely use my router's speed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the server connected to the router? WiFi?

Comment: Yes, it is connected through WIFI.

Comment: I don't get it -  So how could it work if the WiFi is off?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

1) Looks like you using bridged networking in VM config. When your network adapter is connected to real network - you can interact with your VM via network bridge. When it's not connected - your bridge is also closed. If you need to interact with your VM without WiFi connection - you can add one more virtual network adapter to you VM config: use "Host-only" adapter and configure it on both VM and host PC. Your VM will use new host-only adapter to interact with your PC, and old bridged adapter to interact with other network.

2) Check your WiFi speed near the router. Maybe it's too far or provides too weak signal.

PS. Sorry for my poor english.